# Rails How to find record when searching on association of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three tables: `users`, `cars`, and `mechanics`.

associations:

- user has_many cars, car belongs to user
- car belongs_to mechanic, machanic has_many cars

I want to find users with cars repaired by a specific mechanic, so I'm doing something like this:

`User.joins(:cars).where('cars.color = ? AND cars.type = ? AND cars.mechanic.name = ?', 'green', 'estate', 'paul')`

The trick is that I don't know how to write this `cars.mechanic.name` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User
  .joins( :cars => :mechanic )
  .where( :cars     => {:color => "green", :type => "estate"}, 
          :mechanic => {:name => "paul"} )
```

Try this may be this will work.

Comment: I can only add the possibility of using `merge`, so one can use scopes too: `.merge( Mechanic.where(name: 'paul') )`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join in `mechanic` as well and then you can query on it:

```
q = User.joins(cars: :mechanic)
q = q.where('cars.color = ? and cars.type = ?', 'green', 'estate')
q = q.where('mechanics.name = ?', 'paul')
```

You'll need to watch out though because you are then potentially returning multiple `User` instances. If a user has two cars (two green estates) in this example then they will be returned twice by that query. Yo get round that you probably want to add a `distinct` on the query too to only return a user once regardless of how many of their green estates Paul may be attending to.

```
q = q.distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

An association *has_many* can be extended with *through* option, see [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Cardinality+and+associations) for more details. Specific to your question Car model belongs to both User and Mechanic, so this should help you:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  has_many :mechanics, through: :cars
end


class Mechanic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  has_many :users, through: :cars
end


class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :mechanic
end


class MechanicsController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    @mechanic = Mechanic.find_by(name: params[:name])
    @users    = @mechanic.users.includes(:cars)
  end
end
```